# Mongoose Strict rule will not accept Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use the update method in Mongoose to update my MongoDB database. I have the following Schema:

```
let DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,
  data_hourly: [{
    id: Number
  }]
```

Now I want to update my db using :

```
let queryOptions = {
  upsert: true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
  strict: true
}
let queryFields = {
  $addToSet : {
    data_hourly : {
      id: 12345
    }
  }
}
Data.update({ _id: my._id},
  queryFields, queryOptions,
  err => {
    if (err) throw err
})
```

This only works if I set `strict` to `false`. Otherwise it will throw the error:

```
MongoError: '$addToSet' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$addToSet: {<field>: ...}}
```

I understand the error is because Mongoose ignores any extra fields that dont match the Schema if strict is set to true. But this case, my Schema is correct and the fields are in place. So why is it ignoring this?

Comment: What is actually in `timestamp`. At a guess, you are probably trying to add an array, or it's at least an object of some sort when it should be just a singular value.

Comment: timestamp is just a generated int e.g. 12345

Comment: Generated by what? Show the code. The reason it's being removed is because it does not match the required type for the schema. That's what I am telling you. If you cannot work that out yourself we need to see the code where the input is coming from.

Comment: I've edited the code now to remove timestamp variable to avoid confusion. By inputting the raw number 12345, im still getting the same error

Comment: Change your schema to `data_hourly: [{   id: Number },{ _id: false }]`. Mongoose adds an `_id` to subschema arrays of objects, and it has a alias to that as `id`. So it's likely getting confused. I would have expected a cast error though.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I'm still getting the error. A default _id isnt inserted when not using strict, so I dont think its this. This is so unusual, perhaps mongoose doesnt like nested objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a couple of concepts in the schema design here. The only way you get such a response is due to a mismatch from the data to the schema. You basically never should need to apply `strict: false` in any case unless it is your intent to deliberately work with items that you know to not match a schema, or you don't wish to define a schema at all. Typically a feed with lots of varying properties.

So for the "empty" message, either the data does not match or the schema you actually have assigned to the model in use is not what you think it is.

The only real way to make this clear is by demonstration. Here's how to do what you are attempting to do, done properly:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const hourlySchema = new Schema({
  id: Number
},{ _id: false });

const dataSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  data_hourly: [hourlySchema]
},{ _id: false });

const Data = mongoose.model('Data', dataSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map( m => conn.models[m].remove() )
    );


    let data = [
      { _id: 12345, data_hourly: 12345 },
      { _id: 12345, data_hourly: 98765 },
      { _id: 12345, data_hourly: 98765 }
    ];

    for ( let item of data ) {

      let doc = await Data.findByIdAndUpdate(item._id,
        { $addToSet: { data_hourly: { id: item.data_hourly } } },
        { new: true, upsert: true }
      );

      log(doc);
    }


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Which shows you that everything works perfectly:

```
Mongoose: datas.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: datas.findAndModify({ _id: 12345 }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$addToSet': { data_hourly: { id: 12345 } } }, { new: true, upsert: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "__v": 0,
  "data_hourly": [
    {
      "id": 12345
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: datas.findAndModify({ _id: 12345 }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$addToSet': { data_hourly: { id: 98765 } } }, { new: true, upsert: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "__v": 0,
  "data_hourly": [
    {
      "id": 12345
    },
    {
      "id": 98765
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: datas.findAndModify({ _id: 12345 }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$addToSet': { data_hourly: { id: 98765 } } }, { new: true, upsert: true, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "__v": 0,
  "data_hourly": [
    {
      "id": 12345
    },
    {
      "id": 98765
    }
  ]
}
```

Fields named `_id` or `id` in particular need to be attended with `_id: false` in the schema options. MongoDB uses `ObjectId` by default, and mongoose schemas try to apply this by default. This is the thing you specifically need to turn off instead of `"strict"` which is "brute force" applying that no schema rules are taken into account at all. Which defeats the purpose of having a schema defined.

Comment: Thanks for the time in providing this answer. It indirectly helped me find the issue via the use of { strict: 'throw' }. It was simply a type mismatch. The initial error given by Mongoose provided absolutely no help in troubleshooting ! Thanks again